# Wrong siteUrl chosen in multi-environment config

Tags: config, multi-environment, siteurl, multi-domain

I have following setup for my site urls (after other testing domains):

```
return [

    '*' => [
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
        'usePathInfo' => true,
        'generateTransformsBeforePageLoad' => false,
        'convertFilenamesToAscii' => true,
    ],

    'mp.mydevserver.pizza' => [
        'devMode' => true,

        'siteUrl' => [
            'en' => 'http://mp.mydevserver.pizza',
            'de' => 'http://mp.mydevserver.pizza/de',
        ],
    ],

    'mypage.com.mydevserver.pizza' => [
        'siteUrl' => [
            'en' => 'http://mypage.com.mydevserver.pizza',
            'de' => 'http://mypage.com.mydevserver.pizza/de',
        ],
    ],

    'mypage.com' => [
        'siteUrl' => [
            'en' => 'http://mypage.com',
            'de' => 'http://mypage.com/de',
        ],
    ],

];
```

The staging domain is `mp.mydevserver.pizza`

The acceptance domain is `mypage.com.mydevserver.pizza`.

The production domain is  `mypage.com`

Staging works fine. But on Acceptance, Craft always uses `mypage.com` as Site Url. I can reach the site, but ofc, every link is wrong. I've read that in this case the order matters and the `mypage.com.mydevserver.pizza` would have to appear first. But it actually IS before the `mypage.com` entry in the array?

Why is it picking the wrong settings?

Thanks, Robert